# How to split the last string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-remoting

I have a column that look something like this in my csv file

```
SharePoint\user\Documents\2021_Changes_v2048.csv
SharePoint\user\Documents\ACB Client Repair\Client MSI's\CE1.3\CE16098\CE16098-Global\Agree.hta
SharePoint\user\Documents\ACB Client Repair\Client MSI's\AgentSetup_881.msi
```

I'm just wondering how can I get only the last string like this

```
2021_Changes_v2048.csv
Agree.hta
AgentSetup_881.msi
```

I've try like this but some reason it's not working yet

```
$result = "SharePoint\mz1tl6_nam_corp_gm_com\Documents\2020_Changes_v512.csv"
$result.split("\",3)[-2]
```

Not really sure how to get the string only after the last backslash .

Comment: `[IO.Path]::GetFileName(...)` do this for each item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two easiest options are either [`Split-Path -Leaf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7.2#-leaf) or an API call to [`[IO.Path]::GetFileName(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=net-6.0#system-io-path-getfilename(system-string)). Assuming you will want objects out of these for future export, here is how it looks:

```
$paths = @"
SharePoint\user\Documents\2021_Changes_v2048.csv
SharePoint\user\Documents\ACB Client Repair\Client MSI's\CE1.3\CE16098\CE16098-Global\Agree.hta
SharePoint\user\Documents\ACB Client Repair\Client MSI's\AgentSetup_881.msi
"@ -split '\r?\n'

$paths | Select-Object @{ N='FileName'; E={ [IO.Path]::GetFileName($_) }}
$paths | Select-Object @{ N='FileName'; E={ Split-Path $_ -Leaf }}
```

Comment: the paths are incomplete how do you know the driveletter/unc path?

Comment: @Toni OP is only interested in the path's Leaf, so no need to know that

Comment: [IO.Path]::GetFileName($_) doesn't this get the properties from the file?

Comment: @Toni I think you're confusing it with `[IO.File]::GetAttributes`

Comment: indeed, then its a nice one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your file does not look like a CSV, if thats the whole content its simply a textfile, so you can do:

```
#load file
$content = gc [path]

#split at '\' and output last string
$content | %{($_ -split '\\')[-1]}

#output
2021_Changes_v2048.csv
Agree.hta
AgentSetup_881.msi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Split-Path` built-in function.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7.2#example-2-display-file-names